# GDP and multipoint interpellation

Tags: interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate multiple points between two points in time.  I'm trying to convert an annual forecast to quarterly to fill in the missing data points.

My data:

Historical quarterly GDP Numbers:

[image: GDP numbers]

From: https://www.fin.gov.on.ca/en/economy/ecaccts/

I also have annual forecasts for GDP going out two years. What would be the best method to fill in the missing data points for each quarter?

Comment: It depends on what you will do with the interpolated values.  In some applications it is important to produce "realistic looking" data that exhibit all the variation expected of them; but in other applications the goal is to produce "best estimates" and those typically exhibit as little variation as possible--just the opposite of the first case.  For an illustrated set of examples, see my post (on another SE site) at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14361/664.  "Upsampling" in that context corresponds to changing an annual series to a quarterly series.

Comment: Using the output as an input into a regression used to forecast power demand for an area. Although you should likely not be using GDP numbers to forecast prompt year forecasts in power. But  I'm told I have to use GDP. In a past work group I was in we got a lot better results using basic time series/trend analysis in forecasting the prompt year or two years out. After about 2 to 3 years you had to go into scenario/fundamental analysis.

Comment: Ok, but how will the quarterly forecasts of power demand be used? If the goal is a valuation of the power company’s equity, based on npv of revenue, then a smoother interpolation may be more reliable. If the goal is to evaluate new power infrastructure for the local grid, based on maximum demand in any quarter, then a choppier interpolation may be more reliable.

Comment: Meanwhile, the whole description of this issue as “missing data points” is not helpful, and I would recommend deleting that phrase in the post. That description would be appropriate for starting from a good series of first-quarter GDPs in each year, but you don’t even have that.